# Import less file in package

Tags: javascript, meteor, less, meteorite

I've got a `preamble.lessimport` file with definitions of standard colors, sizes, mixins etc. that I import in all other `.less` files. So far, the file was placed in `/client` and I included it with

```
@import '/client/preamble.lessimport';
```

Worked as a charm.

Now, I'm moving all styles to a smart package to make them reusable. How do I include the preamble now?

I've tried putting it as `preamble.lessimport` in the main package dir and then including with both

```
@import '/preamble.lessimport';
```

and

```
@import 'preamble.lessimport';
```

Both result in the compile error:

```
While building package `theme`:
input: Less compiler error: '/preamble.lessimport' wasn't found
```

Placing the file in a subfolder didn't help. The file is added in `package.js` and I use `less` package in both client and server.

How can I properly import that file?

## Edit:

I've worked around this issue by importing via relative path:

```
@import '../../../preamble.lessimport';
```

However I'm not happy with that solution as the package is on early stage and files inside tends to move a lot. Is there any absolute path I could use?

Comment: Not exactly: the package is `theme`, inside of it there's `preamble.lessimport` file, that I would like to include from other files included in that package.

Comment: May be off topic,but this may helpful to you http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way?utm_content=bufferb60a2&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 0):

As of meteor 0.7 you no longer use the .lessimport extension. Your less files should have the .import.less extension.

Take a look at how the [bootstrap3-less](https://github.com/simison/bootstrap3-less) project imports bootstrap for best use examples.

Comment: Currently both work in the same way. I've changed the extension to `.import.less` and it didn't help.